# How can I set fragment's text from activity

Tags: android, android-layout

When i m setting the text of the fragment from activity i got the NullPointerException,

Main Activity

```
 ProductDetail productDetail = (ProductDetail)findViewById(R.id.pd_details);
    productDetail.setDescription("This is description");

FragmentDescription.java

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_description, null);


ProductDetail.java

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
   tvDescription.setText(description);
}
```

Comment: Add a constructor to your fragment and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FragmentManager`

```
 ProductDetail productDetail = (ProductDetail)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pd_details);    
    productDetail.setDescription("This is description");
```

Comment: @VishawThakkar, use then getSupportFragmentManager(); you're probably using the support library, that's why it happens. I've updated my post

Comment: same problem cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.example.niraj.CustomDesign.ui.ProductDetail'

Comment: @VishawThakkar, please show the definition of ProductDetail. I wonder what base class it extends

Comment: public class ProductDetail extends CardView implements ProductDetailContract{}

Comment: @VishawThakkar see now, you extend the CardView class and try to use it as it were a Fragment, you can't do that, you don't have any fragments in your code.